# Split columns moving in the opposite direction when scrolled - in a continuous loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've seen something similar and have been trying to refactor the JS. I have two columns of content, which when scrolled move in opposite directions. This should also loop continuously. The fundamentals of this are working but I'm not sure if it's massively over engineered? Or if the JS could be better so ensure a smoother results *(seems to be a bit of a jump in the top left - maybe images moving too fast)*?

My main current issue is if I remove the height from the `.project` element. The content will scroll smoothly when scrolling down but not up! The height/length of content will vary so I can't really have a fixed value here.

**Example (also in code snippet):** https://jsfiddle.net/rdowb0y5/1

I will add a 'media query' so that this is only visible on tablet/desktop views and on mobile devices the JS is removed and the content just stacked.

Thanks in advance - really looking forward to some support on this!

**EDIT**

Now I've taken the height out, it works until you resize the browser. I did reorder some CSS, maybe that helped but still very temperamental. Would detecting the height and applying into the JS maybe solve this?

A bit more testing shows that it seems to change between working are not when I reduce the width of the viewport. However if I reduce the width and it stops working correctly, then I reduce the height - it works again on refresh. Hmmmmm.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var num_children=$('.split-loop__left').children().length;
    var child_height=$('.split-loop__right').height() / num_children;
    var half_way=num_children * child_height / 2;
    $(window).scrollTop(half_way);

    function crisscross() {

      var parent=$(".split-loop"); //.first();
      var clone=$(parent).clone();

      var leftSide=$(clone).find('.split-loop__left');
      var rightSide=$(clone).find('.split-loop__right');

      if (window.scrollY > half_way) {
        //We are scrolling up
        $(window).scrollTop(half_way - child_height);

        var firstLeft=$(leftSide).children().first();
        var lastRight=$(rightSide).children().last();

        lastRight.appendTo(leftSide);
        firstLeft.prependTo(rightSide);

      }

      else if (window.scrollY < half_way - child_height) {

        var lastLeft=$(leftSide).children().last();
        var firstRight=$(rightSide).children().first();

        $(window).scrollTop(half_way);
        lastLeft.appendTo(rightSide);
        firstRight.prependTo(leftSide);
      }

      $(leftSide).css('bottom', '-'+ window.scrollY + 'px');
      $(rightSide).css('bottom', '-'+ window.scrollY + 'px');

      $(parent).replaceWith(clone);
    }

    $(window).scroll(crisscross);

  }

);
```

```css
/* Hide Scroll Bars */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* Firefox */
}


/* Basic Styling */

img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}


/* Content will be in these eventually */

.bar-left,
.bar-right {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 48px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.bar-right {
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}


/* Split Loop */

.split-loop {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 48px;
}

.split-loop__left {
  // position: absolute;
  // left: 0%;
  // top: 0%;
  // right: auto;
  // bottom: auto;
  // z-index: 4;
  width: 50%;
}

.split-loop__right {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  right: 48px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: calc(50% - 48px);
}

.project {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="bar-left">

</header>

<div class="bar-right">

</div>

<div class="view">

  <div class="grid split-loop">

    <div class="split-loop__left">

      <div class="grid__item project">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/400" alt="" class="project__media" />
        <h2 class="project__title">Project Title</h2>
        <p class="project__desc">Short Description</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid__item project">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/600/400" alt="" class="project__media" />
        <h2 class="project__title">Project Title</h2>
        <p class="project__desc">Short Description</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid__item project">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/400" alt="" class="project__media" />
        <h2 class="project__title">Project Title</h2>
        <p class="project__desc">Short Description</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="split-loop__right">

      <div class="grid__item project">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/600/400" alt="" class="project__media" />
        <h2 class="project__title">Project Title</h2>
        <p class="project__desc">Short Description</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid__item project">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/400" alt="" class="project__media" />
        <h2 class="project__title">Project Title</h2>
        <p class="project__desc">Short Description</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid__item project">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/600/400" alt="" class="project__media" />
        <h2 class="project__title">Project Title</h2>
        <p class="project__desc">Short Description</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```